# Importing namespaces isn't working for an API I just installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, dll

I just got the Google Data API and I can't seem to use it in my application. I got the msi file, built the Google Data API SDK successfully.

Then I went back to my project, right clicked on the Bin folder and selected Add Reference...
From there I added all of the dlls in the C:\Program Files\Google\Google Data API SDK\Redist folder.

Now in my projects when I type:

```
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
```

Google gets underlined in red for all of them, and when I hover over it, it says the namespace "Google" could not be found.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to reference those assemblies in your project.

Go to *Solution Explorer* > right click on *References* > select *Add Reference...*

In the resulting dialog select the *Browse* tab and select your assemblies.

Comment: Didn't work... I have them all referenced and it imported them all to the bin... still doesn't seem to recognize the namespace though

Answer (score 0):

Use ildasm.exe (or better) Reflector to validate the namesapce names in the assembly.

Sometimes they are not what you expect.

Answer (score -2):

Thats Microsoft Visual Studio helping you out.  Fixed below:

```
using Bing.GData.Extensions;
using Bing.GData.Contacts;
using Bing.Contacts;
using Bing.GData.Client;
```

Comment: @Matt: This isn't a real answer - its supposed to be a joke about how Visual Studio wants you to use "Bing" (http://www.bing.com/) instead of Google.  (The downvote was me as well)

Comment: @Matt: I didn't get it before I read the comment either...  kinda funny actually.